# Why does destroy_all and delete_all not work consistently for an ActiveRecord::Relation and ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Why is it that when attempting to call `delete_all` or `destroy_all` on a an instance of `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, and passing it conditions, the `ArgumentError: Valid values are :nullify or :delete_all` error is thrown, whereas `ActiveRecord::Relation#delete_all` does not?

This comes up when attempting to, for example `delete_all`, given a relationship, such as may exist between `Movies` and `Actors`. In this case, given a `Movie` instance, one may want to do something like:

`movie.actors.delete_all(id: [2,3,4])`

The above does not work, throwing an error.

The same is true for their counterpart `#destroy_all`.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the old question I thought I'd drop an answer.

`ActiveRecord::Relation` and `ActiveRecord::Associations` work differently and can be annoying. They are highly useful though when using destroy to make sure you don't have a DB full of orphans.

That said back to what you were trying to do.

To delete an array of data using active record:

```
YourApplication::Models::YourClass.destroy_all(selector: value)
```

DO NOT do this: (This code is incorrect)

```
YourApplication::Models::YourClass.find(selector: value).destroy_all
```

To delete an array that has already been returned

```
data_to_delete = YourApplication::Models::YourClass.find(selector: value).destroy_all
data_to_delete.each(&:destroy)
```

**Back to the specific question**

This code is incorrect

```
movie.actors.delete_all(id: [2,3,4])
```

The problem here is your using an AR association to return an array of data and then calling .delete_all on that data (Then hoping that the args of delete_all will act as a SQL type WHERE IN. This is sadly not how AR works.)

The correct way to do this

```
actors.delete_all(args)
```

Where args will be something like `movie: 'titanic', id: [1,2,3]`

I hope that helps anyone reading this in the future. Be very careful when using delete with associations as Active Record will auto kill orphan data. Delete is the safer option if your unsure.

Comment: I don't quite get difference between the last two code samples. Could you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 1):

Though it seems like they ought to behave identically, and follow the principle of least surprise, actually behave very surprisingly and differently:

`ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy#delete_all` and its counterpart `#destroy_all` take as its argument a `dependent` parameter, whose default value is `nil`. This is very different from how `ActiveRecord::Relation#delete_all` works, which takes a set of conditions, such as those that may be passed to a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

So, given the `Actor` model from above, one may do:

`Actor.delete_all(id: [2,3,4])`

But, one may not grab a `Movie's` associated `Actor` records via the associatino proxy and then invoke `delete_all` on that.